# CreateRoles() moving from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Currently .NET 6 does not use `startup.cs` and only uses `program.cs`. I am trying to move everything over to use only `program.cs` but have some issues at the  `CreateRoles()` portion.

In my .NET 3.1 I changed

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
```

I have `CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();` in my `Configure` function and

```
public async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            string[] roleNames = { "UserManager", "Manager", "Worker", "User" };

            IdentityResult identityResult;

            foreach(var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
                if (!roleExist)
                {
                    identityResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                }
            }

            var usermanager = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("UserManager@UserManager.com");
            if (usermanager == null)
            {
                var userManager = new IdentityUser { UserName = "UserManager@UserManager.com", Email = "UserManager@UserManager.com", EmailConfirmed = true };
                var createUserManager = await UserManager.CreateAsync(userManager,"UserManager2022!");
                if (createUserManager.Succeeded)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userManager, "UserManager");
                }
            }
        }
```

I removed the function name and added its contents directly to `program.cs` and removed
`CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();` but now my project won't even run. The project is able to build successfully but when running it wont connect to web server. If I was to go back to having both `startup.cs` and `program.cs` the project runs with no issues.

This is currently what I have on `program.cs`.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default Connection")));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ManagementContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default Connection")));
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProductInterface,ProductRepo>();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var serviceScope = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDBContext>();
    //context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); //Add to clear db at startup.
    context.Database.Migrate();
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

var UserManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
var RoleManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
string[] roleNames = { "UserManager", "Manager", "Worker", "User" };

IdentityResult identityResult;

foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
{
    var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
    if (!roleExist)
    {
        identityResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
    }
}

var usermanager = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("UserManager@UserManager.com");
if (usermanager == null)
{
    var userManager = new IdentityUser { UserName = "UserManager@UserManager.com", Email = "UserManager@UserManager.com", EmailConfirmed = true };
    var createUserManager = await UserManager.CreateAsync(userManager, "UserManager2022!");
    if (createUserManager.Succeeded)
    {
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userManager, "UserManager");
    }
}

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I know a solution would just be to create a `startup.cs` and `program.cs` but I want to use just `program.cs`.

Comment: Your project won't even run? Why not? What's preventing it? Does it compile? Does it get a runtime error? Please be specific.

Comment: It is able to compile. When running it fails to connect to web server. When I revert the changes back to have both `program.cs` and `startup.cs` the project runs with no issues.

Comment: Fails to connect to what web server? Fails how? Are you getting an exception? Please *be specific*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like below ?

After you call builder.Build() the app.Services resolves as an IServiceProvider.

```
var app = builder.Build();
CreateRolesAsync(app.Services);
...
app.Run();
async Task CreateRolesAsync( IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{..}
```

Comment: Yes something like that. Figured out it had to be
 `CreateRoles(app).Wait(); 
...
static async Task CreateRoles(WebApplication app)
{
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var UserManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
var RoleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
...`